# How to slice/index data in c

Tags: c

I am trying to learn C and have recieved a homework assignment to write code which can read data from a .txt file and print out particular lines.

I wrote the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
char str[5];
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("data.txt","r");
int i;

for (i=1;i<=5;i++){
    fgets(str,5,fp);
    printf("%d \n",i);
    if (i==1||i==3||i==5) {
        printf("%s \n \n",str);
    }
}
}
```

The file data.txt is just the following:

```
3.21
5.22
4.67
2.31
2.51
1.11
```

I had read that each time fgets is run, the pointer is updated to point to the next line. I thought I could keep running fgets and then only print the string `str` when at the correct value for i (the line I want output on the console).

It partially worked, here is the output:

```
1
3.21

2
3
5.22

4
5
4.67


Process returned 8 (0x8)   execution time : 0.024 s
Press any key to continue.
```

It did only print when `i` had the correct values, but for some reason it only printed the first 3 lines, even though `fgets` was supposed to have been run 5 times by the last iteration, and so the pointer should have been reading the last line.

Can someone explain why the pointer did not update as expected and if there is an easier way to slice or index through a file in c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for (at least) two additional characters, in addition to the numbers you have in the file. There is the end-of-line delimiter (`\n` on UNIX/Mac, or possibly `\r\n` on Windows... so maybe 3 additional characters), plus (from the `fgets` documentation):

> A terminating null character is automatically appended after the characters copied to str.

A lot of the C functions that manipulate character arrays (ie. strings) will give you this extra null "for free" and it can be tricky if you forget about it.

Also, a better way to loop over the lines might be:

```
#define MAX_CHARS 7

char buf[MAX_CHARS];
while((fgets(buf, MAX_CHARS, fp)) != NULL) {
  printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

It's still not the best way to do it (no error checking) but a little more compact/readable and idiomatic C, IMO.

Comment: Isn't the "newline" two characters on Windows?

Comment: Ah allowing the str to take in additional characters fixed the problem. Although im not sure I understand why not allowing sufficient characters leads to the behaviour of the pointer not iterating correctly. I dont see how the two problems relate.

Comment: @V.Jain The second argument to `fgets()` is where I think you're getting tripped up. It will read `num-1` characters from the input, and the last character is reserved for the `\0` null character. So `fgets(str, 5, fp)` is reading only *4* characters from the file each time it runs.

Comment: @Z4-tier even if it only reads 4 characters, and so does not manage to read the full line, surely the pointer should still point to the next line with each iteration of the loop? What I am struggling to understand is why if the entire line is not read, the pointer points to the 3rd line in the 5th iteration, while if I give `fgets` enough characters to read so it can read the full line, it points properly to the 5th line in the 5th iteration.

Comment: `fgets` will read from the input stream until it finds a newline/EOF, or until it has read`n-1` characters (`n` being the second argument in the function call), whichever happens first. So if we have `3.21`, the call `fgets(str, 5, fp)`, then in the first loop iteration it will read the 4 characters and stop on the newline. The next loop iteration picks up just that newline and stops. The third iteration starts on the next line and reads 4 characters. In general, even numbered iterations will read a newline, and odd numbered iterations will begin at the start of the line and read 4 characters.

Comment: In other words, the cursor is going to stay right where it left off from the previous call to `fgets`. If a call to `fgets` results in a `\n` being read, then the next call will begin from the start of the next line. If it reads until the maximum number of characters without a newline, the next call picks up right where the previous call left off.